# How can I make the 'previous' button return to the first slide properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I am doing a course for JavaScript in Coursera and there is a project to create an image slide using jQuery. The button for the "next" image is working fine, but the "previous" button is not working that well. What the project tries to do is use jQuery to create an animation so that when you reach the end of the images, it will not transport you to the first image, but will smoothly continue to the first as if it were changing naturally. It is difficult to explain with only words. Here is the full code below.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  'use strict';

  const imageCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
  const imageWidth = $('#slider ul li img').first().width();
  const totalWidth = (imageCount * imageWidth) + "px";

  let leftPosition = 0;
  let counter = 0;

  $('#slider ul').css('width', totalWidth);

  $('#next').click(function() {
    counter++;

    if (counter === imageCount) {

      $('#slider ul').clone().appendTo('#slider');
      $('#slider ul').last().css('left', imageWidth);

      leftPosition = -(totalWidth);

      $('#slider ul').last().animate({
        left: 0
      }, 700, 'easeInQuad');
      $('#slider ul').first().animate({
        left: leftPosition
      }, 700, 'easeInQuad', function() {
        $('#slider ul').first().remove();
      });

      counter = 0;

    } else {
      leftPosition = -(counter * imageWidth) + 'px';
      $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: leftPosition
      }, 700, 'easeInQuad');
    }
  });

  $('#previous').click(function() {
    counter--;

    if (counter < 0) {
      counter = imageCount - 1

      $('#slider ul').clone().appendTo('#slider');
      $('#slider ul').last().css('left', -totalWidth);

      leftPosition = -(counter * imageWidth) + 'px';

      $('#slider ul').last().animate({
        left: leftPosition
      }, 700, 'easeInQuad');
      $('#slider ul').first().animate({
        left: imageWidth + 'px'
      }, 700, 'easeInQuad', function() {
        $('#slider ul').first().remove();
      });

    } else {
      leftPosition = -(counter * imageWidth) + 'px';
      $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: leftPosition
      }, 700, 'easeInQuad');
    };
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 100px;
  background: #717171;
}

#slider {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 10px solid #4C4C4C;
  height: 266px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

#slider ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
}

#slider ul li img {
  display: block;
}


/********** Link Styles ***********/

#links {
  width: 420px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#links a {
  display: block;
  width: 210px;
  background: #6C0204;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #D5D5D5;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

#links a:hover {
  background: #A51D1F;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-3gJwYpMe3QewGELv8k/BX9vcqhryRdzRMxVfq6ngyWXwo03GFEzjsUm8Q7RZcHPHksttq7/GFoxjCVUjkjvPdw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-57oZ/vW8ANMjR/KQ6Be9v/+/h6bq9/l3f0Oc7vn6qMqyhvPd1cvKBRWWpzu0QoneImqr2SkmO4MSqU+RpHom3Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="slider">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/400/266" alt="slideshow image"></li>
    <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/400/266?" alt="slideshow image"></li>
    <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/400/266?0" alt="slideshow image"></li>
    <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/400/266?1" alt="slideshow image"></li>
    <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/400/266?2" alt="slideshow image"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<p id="links">
  <a href="#" id="previous">previous</a>
  <a href="#" id="next">next</a>
</p>
```

Hope someone will be able to help me with this. Thank you